# How would you create a option to retry in Python?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm a little confused on how to allow the user to retry entering something in Python. I created an example code bellow. I want it so if the user types a invalid answer other than 1 or 2 it allows them to try again.

```
import sys

def start():
    print "Hello whats your name?"
    username = raw_input("> ")
    print "Okay, welcome to the game %s" % username
    print "Do you want to hear the background of the game?"
    print "1. Yes"
    print "2. No"

    background = raw_input("> ")

    if background == "1":
            print "Background goes here."

    elif background == "2":
        print "Background skipped"
start()
```

How would I incorporate a try again option into this example? Thanks!

Comment: You will need to wrap the code that you want to repeat in a loop. Then just break out of the loop if the input is 1 or 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a while loop:

```
def start():
    print "Hello whats your name?"
    username = raw_input("> ")
    print "Okay, welcome to the game %s" % username
    print "Do you want to hear the background of the game?"
    print "1. Yes"
    print "2. No"
    while True:                            # Repeat the following block of code infinitely
        background = raw_input("> ")

        if background == "1":
            print "Background goes here."
            break                            # Break out of loop if we get valid input
        elif background == "2":
            print "Background skipped"
            break                            # Break out of loop if we get valid input
        else:
            print "Invalid input. Please enter either '1' or '2'"   # From here, program jumps back to the beginning of the loop

start()
```